# How to make Make generates headers before compiling?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I struggle to compile my CPP files because a header file is missing. I know it is missing because I want to generate it. How ?

Here what I have so far. Problem is : when "the_header.hpp" is used in several CPP files, recursive calls of make are not efficient (nor satisfactory) as headers included in "the_header.hpp" seem to be rebuilt several times because of **parallelism**.

The CPP files %.cpp :

```
#include "the_header.hpp"

// ...
```

My Makefile  :

```
#
include *.g *.d

# *.g like generator
%.g: %.cpp
    g++ -MM -MF $@ -MP -MG -MT $@ $<
    make $@

#
%.d: %.g ;

#
%.o : %.cpp %.d
    // g++ with auto-dependencies generation

# the_header.hpp matches
%.hpp : %.lcm
    // Generate it
```

And just to be cleared of my intensions : as I compile a CPP files, I generate a %.g files which target will add more prerequisites to itself. The recursive call will end up sees "the_header.hpp" as prerequisite (and not up-to-date), generate it and regenerate %.g. The recursive call will see "the_header.hpp" up-to-date, nothing to do, end of recursions. Processes to compiling.

Moreover, "the_header.hpp" is a LCM generated file with lcmgen from %.lcm file.

Before doing so, I had just (which works great with parallelism but is neither satisfactory) :

```
#
%.o : %.cpp %.d $(patsubst %.lcm,%.hpp,$(wildcard *.lcm)
```

Not knowing which lcm files was actually used. Also, I have mixed C and C++ projects which could lead to :

```
# lcmgen can be used with both C++ or C...
%.o : %.cpp %.d $(patsubst %.lcm,%.hpp,$(wildcard *.lcm) $(patsubst %.lcm,%.h,$(wildcard *.lcm)
```

I hope you will find it entertaining !

Comment: *"which works great with parallelism but is neither satisfactory)"* why not satisfactory?

Comment: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ might interest you.

Comment: @Jarod42 neither satisfactory because I put all possibilities not the only ones I need

Comment: @Jarod42 Also, I apply what is in http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ :)

Comment: It should be `$(wildcard *.g *.d)`. Moreover why do you `make $@` in `%.g : %.cpp` when you just have created it in the previous line? Plus: really *always* include the error message which you get, just to be extra clear what we are talking about.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I call make again to trigger the construction of the prerequisites I just created. A lot is missing here as it is a theorical question ;) neither error message !

Comment: I don't think it makes sense inside the recipe of a target to recursively call make on this very target again. It rather looks like you didn't understand the contract which make is working on - or can you explain why that would make sense for a case that I just can't think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use any form of modern automatic generation of prerequisites with constructed headers.  Any compiler-based prerequisite generator will just fail when the header doesn't exist.

For generated headers you pretty much don't have any reasonable option other than to explicitly declare prerequisites.  There's no reason you need to do that inside the pattern rule, though, and that just adds lots of complexity.

Suppose you have source files `foo.c`, `bar.c`, and `baz.c` and the first two depend on the generated header but the last one didn't.  Just add these lines to your makefile:

```
foo.o bar.o : the_header.hpp
```

That's it.  No need to mess with the pattern rules.

Comment: I'm not clear about my options here. I understand that you want to keep the Makefile "standard". If I still want to generate automatically the prerequisite the_header.hpp for a target, you would recommand to do it outside and before executing the Makefile assuming that I can not (don't want to) explicitly write prerequisites (and doing so is outside the scope of my original question).

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by _keep the Makefile "standard"_.  Anyway, the answer to the problem of parallelism rebuilding things multiple times etc. is to add prerequisites.  That's the only solution provided by make.  If you don't want to do that for some strange reason, then your only option is to use a solution outside of make.  One such solution would be, yes, to have a wrapper script that always first builds the header then builds the rest.  It sounds bizarre to me but I'm obviously not familiar with your environment so what do I know?

Comment: I completely agree with you ! I need the prerequisites, I'm just looking for a way to write them but make seems not to be the answer and that's fine :) gcc is used for prerequisites determination, I need something equivalent I guess

Comment: I don't understand: I showed what you need to do to write them, by adding an explicit dependency line such as the last example in my answer.

Comment: In my comments above I wrote "Moreover why do you make $@ in %.g : %.cpp when you just have created it in the previous [recipe-] line?....I don't think it makes sense inside the recipe of a target to recursively call make on this very target again.". Do I err or is it really pointless to do that? To the best of my make-knowledge I think it is but I have a feeling that somehow I am overlooking a scenario.